# State is not formed as a list

Tags: salt-stack

I have a really stupid issue witch cannot resolve ... :(
Looking at the Salt documentation should work but isn't ... - https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html

```
chrome:
  latest:
    full_name: 'Google Chrome'
    installer: 'salt://software/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi'
    uninstaller: 'salt://software/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi'
    install_flags: '/qn /norestart'
    uninstall_flags: '/qn /norestart'
    msiexec: True
    locale: en_US
    reboot: False

putty:
  latest:
    installer: 'salt://software/putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi'
    uninstaller: 'salt://software/putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi'
    full_name:  'PuTTY'
    install_flags: '/qn'
    uninstall_flags: '/qn'
    msiexec: True
    locale: en_US
    reboot: False

winscp:
  latest:
    full_name: 'WinSCP'
    installer: 'salt://software/WinSCP-5.17.10-Setup.exe'
    uninstaller: 'salt://software/WinSCP-5.17.10-Setup.exe'
    install_flags: '/SP- /verysilent /norestart'
    uninstall_flags: '/verysilent'
    msiexec: False
    locale: en_US
    reboot: False
```

I'm getting:

```
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    State 'chrome' in SLS 'software/update-software' is not formed as a list
----------
    State 'putty' in SLS 'software/update-software' is not formed as a list
----------
    State 'winscp' in SLS 'software/update-software' is not formed as a list
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you have displayed in question is a [software definition file](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html#software-definition-files).

*It is not* a `state.sls` file that you can run against minions.

This software definition file can be stored on the master at a path such as: `win/repo-ng/custom_defs` (default location). It is configurable in master config with `winrepo_dir_ng`.

Example `win/repo-ng/custom_defs/putty.sls`:

```yaml
putty:
  latest:
    installer: 'salt://software/putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi'
    uninstaller: 'salt://software/putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi'
    full_name:  'PuTTY'
    install_flags: '/qn'
    uninstall_flags: '/qn'
    msiexec: True
    locale: en_US
    reboot: False
```

Then in a state file like `config_windows.sls`:

```yaml
install-putty:
  pkg.installed:
  - name: putty
  - version: latest
```

Now this `pkg.installed` will refer to our custom definition file `putty.sls` and install/manage PuTTY.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you define multiple software products in the same SLS file? According to [the page you cite](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html):

> There can be only one short name in the file

As a sidenote, have you considered just using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)? It has packages for Chrome, Putty and WinSCP, and there is a [state module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.chocolatey.html) to use it.